# How to nest formdata with file in Katalon api request

Tags: rest, katalon-studio

I'm trying to set up a visual regression test and have decided to use Spectre for screenshot comparison. Having trouble figuring out how to Post the screenshot using Katalons API calls
the request I'm trying to send:

```
POST /tests
test:
run_id: {run_id from above},
name: Homepage,
platform: OSX,
browser: PhantomJS,
size: 1024,
screenshot: <File>,
crop_area: '640x480+50+100'
```

I'm obviously not nesting this correctly but can't find anyway to nest the parameters under "test"

My code

```
RequestObject ro2 = new RestRequestObjectBuilder()
                .withRestUrl(endpoint)
                .withHttpHeaders(defaultHeaders)
                .withRestRequestMethod("POST")
                .withMultipartFormDataBodyContent([
                    new FormDataBodyParameter('run_id', '7', 'PARAM_TYPE_TEXT'),
                    new FormDataBodyParameter('name', 'Homepage',  'PARAM_TYPE_TEXT'),
                    new FormDataBodyParameter( 'platform', 'Windows', 'PARAM_TYPE_TEXT'),
                    new FormDataBodyParameter( 'browser', 'Chrome', 'PARAM_TYPE_TEXT'),
                    new FormDataBodyParameter( 'size', '1024', 'PARAM_TYPE_TEXT'),
                    new FormDataBodyParameter( 'screenshot', "C:\\Users\\aalago\\Desktop\\paths\\devscreens\\fb vt-new-and-popular-SplitView_TabPaneB4B2Article_ArticleNewPopularCombined.png", 'PARAM_TYPE_FILE')
                ])
                .build()

        ResponseObject respObj2 = WS.sendRequest(ro2)
```